# (nucleus):IDT 4.7.0 for greengrass v2 cloudcomponent test failed Failed at 'the Greengrass deployment is COMPLETED on the device after 180 seconds

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, aws-iot-core, aws-iot-greengrass

Hope someone can help me out with this ; stuck on the error for days

**Describe the Error**

Running IDT shows error in cloudcomponent log

```
the Greengrass deployment is COMPLETED on the device after 180 seconds
```

comes up with

```
2023-Mar-29 10:22:22,494 [cloudComponent] [idt-c057b1fc3d6bc618a399] [ERROR] greengrass/features/cloudComponent.feature - Failed at step: 'the Greengrass deployment is COMPLETED on the device after 180 seconds'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Deployment idt-c057b1fc3d6bc618a399-gg-deployment did not reach COMPLETED
        at com.aws.greengrass.testing.features.DeploymentSteps.deploymentSucceeds(DeploymentSteps.java:311) ~[AWSGreengrassV2TestingIDT-1.0.jar:?]
        at ✽.the Greengrass deployment is COMPLETED on the device after 180 seconds(classpath:greengrass/features/cloudComponent.feature:26) ~[?:?]
2023-Mar-29 10:22:22,510 [cloudComponent] [idt-c057b1fc3d6bc618a399] [INFO] greengrass/features/cloudComponent.feature - Finished step: 'the com.aws.HelloWorld log on the device contains the line "Hello World!!" within 20 seconds' with status SKIPPED
```

```
2023-03-28T05:33:39.019Z [ERROR] (Copier) com.aws.greengrass.util.orchestration.SystemdUtils: systemd-setup. {stderr=Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/greengrass.service → /etc/systemd/system/greengrass.service., command=systemctl enable greengrass.service}
```

It seems like the mqtt test also have same error in the log after a couple times of trying  not sure the  problem related to the error

but some how the mqtt test pass

```
./mqtt/mqttpubsub/greengrass_2023_03_29_01_0.log:2023-03-29T01:59:34.313Z [ERROR] (Copier) com.aws.greengrass.util.orchestration.SystemdUtils: systemd-setup. {stderr=Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/greengrass.service → /etc/systemd/system/greengrass.service., command=systemctl enable greengrass.service}
```

Details:

I am tyring to use IDT for greengrass v2 following
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/device-config-setup.html
by following the official guide

after by launching greengrass with

`sudo -E java -Droot="/test/greengrass/v2" -Dlog.store=FILE -jar ./GreengrassInstaller/lib/Greengrass.jar --aws-region us-west-2 --thing-name IM30 --thing-group-name GreengrassQuickStartGroup_test --component-default-user root:root --provision true --setup-system-service true --deploy-dev-tools true`

it shows

"Successfully set up Nucleus as a system service"

while watching systemctl status greengrass.service

```
root@i350-evk:/test/greengrass/v2# systemctl status greengrass.service
● greengrass.service - Greengrass Core
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/greengrass.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-03-29 02:46:35 UTC; 16s ago
   Main PID: 11178 (sh)
      Tasks: 68 (limit: 3443)
     Memory: 277.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/greengrass.service
             ├─11178 /bin/sh /test/greengrass/v2/alts/current/distro/bin/loader
             └─11182 java -Dlog.store=FILE -Dlog.store=FILE -Droot=/test/greengrass/v2 -jar /test/greengrass/v2/alts/current/distro/lib/Greengrass.jar --setup-system-service false

Mar 29 02:46:35 i350-evk systemd[1]: Started Greengrass Core.
Mar 29 02:46:35 i350-evk sh[11178]: Greengrass root: /test/greengrass/v2
Mar 29 02:46:35 i350-evk sh[11178]: Java executable: java
Mar 29 02:46:35 i350-evk sh[11178]: JVM options: -Dlog.store=FILE -Droot=/test/greengrass/v2
Mar 29 02:46:35 i350-evk sh[11178]: Nucleus options: --setup-system-service false
Mar 29 02:46:39 i350-evk sh[11182]: Launching Nucleus...
Mar 29 02:46:46 i350-evk sh[11182]: Launched Nucleus successfully.

Mar 29 02:46:35 i350-evk systemd[1]: Started Greengrass Core.
Mar 29 02:46:35 i350-evk sh[11178]: Greengrass root: /test/greengrass/v2
Mar 29 02:46:35 i350-evk sh[11178]: Java executable: java
Mar 29 02:46:35 i350-evk sh[11178]: JVM options: -Dlog.store=FILE -Droot=/test/greengrass/v2
Mar 29 02:46:35 i350-evk sh[11178]: Nucleus options: --setup-system-service false
Mar 29 02:46:39 i350-evk sh[11182]: Launching Nucleus...
Mar 29 02:46:46 i350-evk sh[11182]: Launched Nucleus successfully.
```

however while I launch the deployment of idt with command:

`./devicetester_linux_x86-64 run-suite --suite-id GGV2Q_2.5.0 --userdate userdata.json`

the test_manager.log in idt shows

```
[ERROR] [2023-03-28 16:56:12]: Test exited unsuccessfully testCaseId=cloudcomponent error=exit status 1 executionId=9f12b10c-cd42-11ed-bb24-080027641c32
[INFO] [2023-03-28 16:56:12]: All tests finished. executionId=9f12b10c-cd42-11ed-bb24-080027641c32
[INFO] [2023-03-28 16:56:13]:

========== Test Summary ==========
Execution Time:         26m50s
Tests Completed:        7
Tests Passed:           6
Tests Failed:           1
Tests Skipped:          0
----------------------------------
Test Groups:
    lambdadeployment:           PASSED
    mqtt:                       PASSED
    component:                  FAILED
    pretestvalidation:          PASSED
    coredependencies:           PASSED
    version:                    PASSED
----------------------------------
Failed Tests:
    Group Name: component
        Test Name: cloudcomponent
            Reason: Failed at 'the Greengrass deployment is COMPLETED on the device after 180 seconds'
----------------------------------
Path to AWS IoT Device Tester Report: /home/user/test/devicetester_greengrass_v2_linux/results/20230328T162913/awsiotdevicetester_report.xml
Path to Test Execution Logs: /home/user/test/devicetester_greengrass_v2_linux/results/20230328T162913/logs
Path to Aggregated JUnit Report: /home/user/test/devicetester_greengrass_v2_linux/results/20230328T162913/GGV2Q_Report.xml
==================================
```

logs/component/cloudcomponent
greengrass_2023_03_28_05_0.log shows:

```
2023-03-28T05:33:10.582Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.deployment.DeviceConfiguration: Copy Nucleus artifacts to component store. {destination=/test/greengrass/v2/packages/artifacts-unarchived/aws.greengrass.Nucleus/2.9.4/aws.greengrass.nucleus, source=/test/GreengrassInstaller}
2023-03-28T05:33:37.517Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: Waiting for services to shutdown. {}
2023-03-28T05:33:37.543Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.Kernel: effective-config-dump-complete. {file=/test/greengrass/v2/config/effectiveConfig.yaml}
2023-03-28T05:33:39.019Z [ERROR] (Copier) com.aws.greengrass.util.orchestration.SystemdUtils: systemd-setup. {stderr=Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/greengrass.service → /etc/systemd/system/greengrass.service., command=systemctl enable greengrass.service}
2023-03-28T05:33:39.889Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.util.orchestration.SystemdUtils: systemd-setup. Successfully set up systemd service. {}
2023-03-28T05:33:39.891Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: system-shutdown. {main=null}
2023-03-28T05:33:39.902Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: Waiting for services to shutdown. {}
2023-03-28T05:33:39.933Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.Kernel: effective-config-dump-complete. {file=/test/greengrass/v2/config/effectiveConfig.yaml}
2023-03-28T05:33:39.937Z [INFO] (Serialized listener processor) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: executor-service-shutdown-initiated. {}
2023-03-28T05:33:39.938Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: Waiting for executors to shutdown. {}
2023-03-28T05:33:39.940Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: executor-service-shutdown-complete. {executor-terminated=true, scheduled-executor-terminated=true}
2023-03-28T05:33:39.941Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: context-shutdown-initiated. {}
2023-03-28T05:33:39.945Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: context-shutdown-complete. {}
```

greengrass-test-run.log shows:

```
2023-Mar-29 10:19:21,514 [cloudComponent] [idt-c057b1fc3d6bc618a399] [INFO] greengrass/features/cloudComponent.feature - Finished step: 'I create a Greengrass deployment with components' with status PASSED
2023-Mar-29 10:19:22,164 [cloudComponent] [idt-c057b1fc3d6bc618a399] [INFO] com.aws.greengrass.testing.resources.AbstractAWSResourceLifecycle - Created GreengrassDeployment in GreengrassV2Lifecycle
2023-Mar-29 10:19:22,165 [cloudComponent] [idt-c057b1fc3d6bc618a399] [INFO] com.aws.greengrass.testing.features.DeploymentSteps - Created Greengrass deployment: fe860f32-3236-4493-b71d-56e585382c0c
2023-Mar-29 10:19:22,166 [cloudComponent] [idt-c057b1fc3d6bc618a399] [INFO] greengrass/features/cloudComponent.feature - Finished step: 'I deploy the Greengrass deployment configuration to thing group' with status PASSED
2023-Mar-29 10:22:22,494 [cloudComponent] [idt-c057b1fc3d6bc618a399] [ERROR] greengrass/features/cloudComponent.feature - Failed at step: 'the Greengrass deployment is COMPLETED on the device after 180 seconds'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Deployment idt-c057b1fc3d6bc618a399-gg-deployment did not reach COMPLETED
        at com.aws.greengrass.testing.features.DeploymentSteps.deploymentSucceeds(DeploymentSteps.java:311) ~[AWSGreengrassV2TestingIDT-1.0.jar:?]
        at ✽.the Greengrass deployment is COMPLETED on the device after 180 seconds(classpath:greengrass/features/cloudComponent.feature:26) ~[?:?]
2023-Mar-29 10:22:22,510 [cloudComponent] [idt-c057b1fc3d6bc618a399] [INFO] greengrass/features/cloudComponent.feature - Finished step: 'the com.aws.HelloWorld log on the device contains the line "Hello World!!" within 20 seconds' with status SKIPPED
2023-Mar-29 10:22:22,511 [cloudComponent] [idt-c057b1fc3d6bc618a399] [INFO] greengrass/features/cloudComponent.feature - Finished step: 'I create a Greengrass deployment with components' with status SKIPPED
2023-Mar-29 10:22:22,512 [cloudComponent] [idt-c057b1fc3d6bc618a399] [INFO] greengrass/features/cloudComponent.feature - Finished step: 'I deploy the Greengrass deployment configuration to thing group' with status SKIPPED
2023-Mar-29 10:22:22,513 [cloudComponent] [idt-c057b1fc3d6bc618a399] [INFO] greengrass/features/cloudComponent.feature - Finished step: 'the Greengrass deployment is COMPLETED on the device after 180 seconds' with status SKIPPED
2023-Mar-29 10:22:22,513 [cloudComponent] [idt-c057b1fc3d6bc618a399] [INFO] greengrass/features/cloudComponent.feature - Finished step: 'the com.aws.HelloWorld log on the device contains the line "Hello World Updated!!" within 20 seconds' with status SKIPPED
```

**To Reproduce**
See above.

**Expected behavior**
IDT for greengrass v2 pass all of the test

**Actual behavior**
IDT for greengrass v2 failed on cloud component test

**Environment**

- OS: device for greengrass Yocto linux aarch64
- device for idt Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
- JDK version:"openjdk version "1.8.0_282"
- //also have test with  amazon-corretto-17.0.6.10.1-linux-aarch64
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-17-ug/downloads-list.html
- seems the error still happened
- Nucleus version:2.9.4
- IDT version:4.7.0

**Additional context**
Notice the same error on https://github.com/aws-greengrass/aws-greengrass-nucleus/issues/876#issuecomment-786948524
not sure if it is related
but other test Pass

the link above show that the config (.yaml) of greengrass causing the error but I　do believe it has been set correctly

see below

my effectiveConfig.yaml :

```
---
system:
  certificateFilePath: "/test/greengrass/v2/thingCert.crt"
  privateKeyPath: "/test/greengrass/v2/privKey.key"
  rootCaPath: "/test/greengrass/v2/rootCA.pem"
  rootpath: "/test/greengrass/v2"
  thingName: "IM30"
services:
  aws.greengrass.LocalHelloWorld:
    componentType: "GENERIC"
    configuration: {}
    dependencies: []
    lifecycle:
      Run: "java -DcomponentName=\"HelloWorld\" -jar /test/greengrass/v2/packages/artifacts/aws.greengrass.LocalHelloWorld/1.0.0/cloudcomponent.jar"
    version: "1.0.0"
  aws.greengrass.Nucleus:
    componentType: "NUCLEUS"
    configuration:
      awsRegion: "us-west-2"
      componentStoreMaxSizeBytes: "10000000000"
      deploymentPollingFrequencySeconds: "15"
      envStage: "prod"
      fleetStatus:
        periodicStatusPublishIntervalSeconds: 86400
      greengrassDataPlaneEndpoint: ""
      greengrassDataPlanePort: "8443"
      httpClient: {}
      interpolateComponentConfiguration: false
      iotCredEndpoint: "xxx.credentials.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
      iotDataEndpoint: "xxx-ats.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
      iotRoleAlias: "GreengrassV2TokenExchangeRoleAlias"
      jvmOptions: "-Dlog.store=FILE"
      logging: {}
      mqtt:
        spooler: {}
      networkProxy:
        proxy: {}
      platformOverride: {}
      runWithDefault:
        posixShell: "sh"
        posixUser: "root:root"
      telemetry: {}
    dependencies: []
    lifecycle:
      bootstrap:
        requiresPrivilege: "true"
        script: "\nset -eu\nKERNEL_ROOT=\"/test/greengrass/v2\"\nUNPACK_DIR=\"/test/greengrass/v2/packages/artifacts-unarchived/aws.greengrass.Nucleus/2.9.4/aws.greengrass.nucleus\"\
          \nrm -r \"$KERNEL_ROOT\"/alts/current/*\necho \"-Dlog.store=FILE\" > \"\
          $KERNEL_ROOT/alts/current/launch.params\"\nln -sf \"$UNPACK_DIR\" \"$KERNEL_ROOT/alts/current/distro\"\
          \nexit 100"
    version: "2.9.4"
  DeploymentService:
    ComponentToGroups:
      aws.greengrass.LocalHelloWorld:
        "4e69ead5-a595-4b96-a7c8-45da74475fe0": "LOCAL_DEPLOYMENT"
    dependencies: []
    GroupToLastDeployment:
      LOCAL_DEPLOYMENT:
        configArn: null
        timestamp: 1679992938275
      thing/IM30:
        configArn: "arn:aws:greengrass:us-west-2:116407744508:configuration:thing/IM30:111"
        timestamp: 1679993636499
      thinggroup/GreengrassQuickStartGroup_test:
        configArn: "arn:aws:greengrass:us-west-2:116407744508:configuration:thinggroup/GreengrassQuickStartGroup_test:51"
        timestamp: 1679993661994
    GroupToRootComponents:
      LOCAL_DEPLOYMENT:
        aws.greengrass.LocalHelloWorld:
          groupConfigArn: "4e69ead5-a595-4b96-a7c8-45da74475fe0"
          groupConfigName: "LOCAL_DEPLOYMENT"
          version: "1.0.0"
      thing/IM30: {}
      thinggroup/GreengrassQuickStartGroup_test: {}
    runtime:
      ProcessedDeployments:
        "1679993661353":
          ConfigurationArn: "arn:aws:greengrass:us-west-2:116407744508:configuration:thing/IM30:111"
          DeploymentId: "arn:aws:greengrass:us-west-2:116407744508:configuration:thing/IM30:111"
          DeploymentRootPackages: []
          DeploymentStatus: "SUCCEEDED"
          DeploymentStatusDetails:
            detailed-deployment-status: "SUCCESSFUL"
          DeploymentType: "SHADOW"
          GreengrassDeploymentId: "ef974963-4dfe-49a4-a1fc-73c8aa49a545"
    version: "0.0.0"
  FleetStatusService:
    dependencies: []
    lastPeriodicUpdateTime: 1679981624527
    sequenceNumber: 122
    version: "0.0.0"
  main:
    dependencies:
    - "FleetStatusService:HARD"
    - "DeploymentService:HARD"
    - "aws.greengrass.LocalHelloWorld"
    - "TelemetryAgent:HARD"
    - "aws.greengrass.Nucleus"
    - "UpdateSystemPolicyService:HARD"
    - "aws.greengrass.Nucleus"
    lifecycle: {}
    runtime:
      service-digest: {}
  TelemetryAgent:
    dependencies: []
    runtime:
      lastPeriodicAggregationMetricsTime: 1679981624784
      lastPeriodicPublishMetricsTime: 1679981624784
    version: "0.0.0"
  UpdateSystemPolicyService:
    dependencies: []
    version: "0.0.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer and details in aws re:post
https://repost.aws/questions/QU9lwv47QcQHWAE0IdCiy5Ig/can-anyone-help-me-out-with-the-idt-error-problem-the-greengrass-deployment-is-completed-on-the-device-after-180-seconds

https://repost.aws/questions/QUfFmnIZhqQTa2qcwMpale-A/nucleus-idt-4-7-0-for-greengrass-v2-cloudcomponent-test-failed-failed-at-the-greengrass-deployment-is-completed-on-the-device-after-180-seconds

after days of research we found out that the security credential cause the problem

```
========== Test Summary ==========
Execution Time:     23m57s
Tests Completed:    7
Tests Passed:       7
Tests Failed:       0
Tests Skipped:      0
----------------------------------
Test Groups:
    coredependencies:       PASSED
    version:            PASSED
    lambdadeployment:       PASSED
    component:          PASSED
    mqtt:           PASSED
    pretestvalidation:      PASSED
----------------------------------
Path to AWS IoT Device Tester Report: /home/user/test/devicetester_greengrass_v2_linux/results/20230407T152513/awsiotdevicetester_report.xml
Path to Test Execution Logs: /home/user/test/devicetester_greengrass_v2_linux/results/20230407T152513/logs
Path to Aggregated JUnit Report: /home/user/test/devicetester_greengrass_v2_linux/results/20230407T152513/GGV2Q_Report.xml
```